# Read value inside XML tag using QXmlStreamReader

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have XML format as

```
<Value active="false">8.0</Value>
```

I am using [QXmlStreamReader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/QXmlStreamReader.html) to parse the XML. I am able to read the tag "Value" and the actual value "8.0", but I am not able to read `active="false">` part of the XML.

```
    const QString label = xmlReader.name().toString();
    xmlReader.readNext();
    const QString text = xmlReader.text().toString();
```

gives me "Value" in `label` and "8.0" in `text`.

I modified code as

```
const QString label = xmlReader.name().toString();
const QString labelIn = xmlReader.readElementText();
xmlReader.readNext();
const QString text = xmlReader.text().toString();
```

But `labelIn` returns an empty string. Am I missing something?

I am using Qt 5.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `active="false"` part of the node is called *attribute*. To get its value you need to use dedicated API of `QXmlStreamReader` class:

```
QXmlStreamAttributes attribs = xmlReader->attributes();
QString attr = attribs.value("active").toString();
```